# Pass string variable from java to php function

Tags: java, php, android

I am a beginner java and php
I must pass a string variable from Java client to php server using WebView

Is what I am doing right?

In java side:

```
String Coords=CoordsString;
String PHPPagePath="http://10.0.2.2/ReceiveLocation.php?Coords=" + CoordsString";
```

and on the php side: 
ReceiveLocation.php

```
 <?php
include('ConnectionFunctions.php');
Connection(); 
$x=$_GET['Coords'];
GetCoords($x);
function GetCoords($x)
{
   echo $x;
}   
?>
```

Is this the right way to pass the parameter Coords from Java Client to PHP Server Function?

Comment: There is nothing in your PHP code that gets any variable from outside... I don't get what you are expecting the PHP script to do.

Comment: I am a beginner I have no Idea how to do that...Could you help me please?

Comment: See my answer: I've done the best I can for such a vague question... :)

Comment: @gd1 Thanks for your corrections, It was really helpful but I do not think my question is vague, other users provided alternative solutions in addition to corrections to the current code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I edited my code and it is working fine. I edited both java and php code=)

Answer (score 2):

To pass a parameter to PHP using the URL of the page, just append `?key=value` to the URL, where `key` is the parameter key (i.e. the name) and `value` is its value (i.e. the data you are trying to transfer), and then in the PHP script you can retrieve the parameter like this:

```
<?php
    echo 'I have received this parameter: '.$_GET['key'];
?>
```

replacing `'key'` with the actual name of the parameter.

This is the way PHP reads HTTP GET variables.
See this for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Please, be careful when accepting variables from outside: they have to be "sanitized", expecially if they are going to be used in database queries or printed in the HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as following

Java code:

```
String Coords=CoordsString;
String PHPPagePath="http://10.0.2.2/ReceiveLocation.php?Coords=10";
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
include('ConnectionFunctions.php');
Connection(); 

function GetCoords(x)
{
echo 'Coords = '.$_GET['Coords'];

}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$_GET['parameter_name']` in `PHP` if you send parameter using `GET` method

OR

use `$_POST['parameter_name']` in `PHP` if you send parameter using `POST` method

and its alternate is also `$_REQUEST` if you send parameter using POST OR GET.

Answer (score 0):

On Java side you have to make a request. As this is http you should use a library like [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html). Your request will contain the data like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://10.0.2.2/ReceiveLocation.php");
method.addParamezter("Coord","1x3x4"); // or whatever
int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
```

Work on the tutorials at httpclient side.

On PHP side youe have to read the posted data...

right now I found this that will help you: http://www.coderblog.de/sending-data-from-java-to-php-via-a-post-request/

Answer (score 0):

> This trick is to process java variable in php !!!'

```
<?php
$java_variable_in_php = 'string'; //Define our  variable.  
?>          
 <script> js_variable_name = "<?php echo $java_variable_in_php; ?>";
 string=' this is my trick to process java variable in php !!!';
 document.write(js_variable_name);//will print java variable name 'string'
 </script>



<?php echo '<script>document.write(js_variable_name)</script>';?>
<?php echo '<script>document.write('.$java_variable_in_php.')'.'</script>';?>
```

> check view source of the output !! Hope this will help someone...